# Replace <div> When Directly Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, swap

I'm looking for some JS code that will replace a div with another when clicked. No outside links or buttons, just simply swapping the div to a new one when clicked anywhere within the original div. I'd also like to make it so that once clicked and swapped clicking it a second time will not swap it back.

Example: I have a box div for a livestream with content in it (schedule information and the like), clicking anywhere on that div will replace it with the actual livestream embed.

Would this even be possible?

Answer (score 3):

Don't understand why everyone is giving jQuery solutions. Here is a pure JavaScript one:

```
var livestream = document.getElementByID('livestream');

document.getElementById('schedule').onclick = function() {
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(livestream, this);
};
```

Here I assumed to that the replacement is part of DOM. Of course you can also dynamically generate it with [`document.createElement`  *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.createElement).

I don't know what you want to do with the replaced element. It is returned by the `replaceChild` method, so you can insert it wherever you want.

**Reference**: [`.replaceChild()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.replaceChild)

Comment: +1 for pure JavaScript (I'm myself so used to jQuery that I automatically think in it), but in your solution #someId appears to be somewhere on the page, which would make the livestream start on page load instead of on click.

Comment: @Cyril: Well, I don't know where `livestream` is. It also where well be that it is dynamically generated. I will mention it though, thanks.

Comment: I don't even know there is a `.replaceChild()` method... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div").click(function(){
   $(this).html('what to write into that div?');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id= "wrapper">
    <div id= "schedule">
        Skedule shedule
    </div>

    <div id= "livestreamWrapper" style= "display: none;">
    </div>
</div>

<script type= "text/javascript">
$("#schedule").click(function()
{
    $(this).hide();
    $("#livestreamWrapper").show()
                           .append(/*actual livestream here*/);
});
</script>
```

I'd recommend having both #schedule and #livestreamWrapper wrapped in a div (#wrapper in my example), less headache with positioning.

Some precautions may be used for visitors with javascript disabled (like originally making both divs visible, actual livestream appended, and hiding #livestreamWrapper and removing the actual livestream on document.ready), but are there any people watching livestreams and not having javascript enabled? :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the pure CSS demo if you want to keep your *`code`* clean:

**Checkboxy:**
　　http://jsfiddle.net/LaHS4/1/

**If you dont like checkbox, then try this demo:**
　　http://jsfiddle.net/E7zVt/1/